# ASIHttprequest login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, asihttprequest

I got the following situation. I'm doing an iPhone app with tabbarcontroller and navigation controller. After using the app to log into a web-server (which provides the webservices) to get a session cookie, I click on the tabbarnavigation menu which makes a request to one of the webservices. Calling this webservice, I got a handle status code that tells me im not logged into server, even though the app had logged into the web-server successfully the first time. So i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong I leave here snippet of my code.

AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    [self initTabBarMenu];

    return YES;
}    
// call when the app is not login
- (void) showLogin 
{
    loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
}
```

LoginViewController

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *username = [defaults objectForKey:@"usernameApp"];
    NSString *password = [defaults objectForKey:@"passwordAp"];

    if (![StrUtil isEmpty:username] && ![StrUtil isEmpty:password])
    {
        userField.text = username;
        passwordField.text = password;
        [self loginCheck];
    }

}

- (void) loginCheck
{
    NSString *url = @"http://localhost/service/login";

     ASIFormDataRequest *theRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [theRequest setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];  
    [theRequest setDelegate:self];
    [theRequest addPostValue:userField.text forKey:@"username"];
    [theRequest addPostValue:passwordField.text forKey:@"password"];
    [theRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(loginDone:)];
    [theRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(loginFailed:)];
    [theRequest startAsynchronous];
    [userField resignFirstResponder];
    [passwordField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void) loginResponse:(ASIFormDataRequest *)theRequest
{
    nsData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[theRequest.responseString JSONValue]];
    [self hideProgress];

    if ([[nsData objectForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 1)
    {

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:userField.text forKey:@"usernameApp"];
        [defaults setObject:passwordField.text forKey:@"passwordApp"]; 
        [defaults synchronize];
        // Remove current view controller
        [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self showAlert:@"Problem"];
    }
}
```

Here is the problem: when i get the menu, Im not getting any data from my webservices, actually the app doesnt even try to call it, I'm using a BaseController to call every single webservice from there so I got my HomeViewController that extends from BaseController, so I got a generic method to call webservice on my BaseController like this:

```
- (void) callRequest
{
    //url is a NSString and you can set on HomeviewController
    if ([StrUtils isEmpty:url]) return;
    request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    //[request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
    [request setCachePolicy:ASIAskServerIfModifiedCachePolicy|ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy];
    [request setSecondsToCache:60*60*24*7]; // Cache for 7 days
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(finishedWithError:)];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:15];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest*)theRequest
{
    NSString *responseString = [theRequest responseString];
    nsData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[responseString JSONValue]];

    if ([[receivedData objectForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 1)
    {
        return [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] showLogin];
    }   
}
```

And then i Call the webservice from viewDidLoad

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self callRequest];

}
```

HomeViewController

```
- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.title = @"My Home";
        self.url = @"http://localhost/services/gethome"
    }

    return self;
}
```

So in summary, the problem is: i can not get any data for any section from my tabbarnavigation. The first time i click on 1 item, it loads loginviewcontroller (even though login was previously successful) and then call the webservice to the login in again. And directly after the second login, i can not get any data.

Well I'm not sure what i can do, thanks for all your suggestion and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be that you're not accepting cookies in your login request. Test to see what the value of your cookies are after the login call.